# Django Many to Many through intermediary table form like admin's TabularInline form?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-orm

I'd like to have a form to add, edit and delete values for a many to many relationship using a specified intermediary table just like what I can get from Django's admin TabularInline form.  Is there a way to do this?  I have not found it in Django's documentation.

I have created a form to edit the UserProfile and would like to be able to add, edit and delete the many to many with UserProfile_Language (both language and proficiency).  How do I make a form for this? How do I handle this in the view?

My Models are as follows:

```
class Language(models.Model):
    LANGUAGE_ENGLISH = 1
    LANGUAGE_FRENCH = 2
    LANGUAGE_CHOICES = (
        (LANGUAGE_ENGLISH, 'English'),
        (LANGUAGE_FRENCH, 'French')
    )

    language = models.SmallIntegerField(choices=LANGUAGE_CHOICES)

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
    languages = models.ManyToManyField(Language, null=True, blank=True, through='UserProfile_Language')

class UserProfile_Language(models.Model):
    FLUENT = 1
    OK = 2
    PROFICIENCY_CHOICES = (
        (FLUENT, 'Fluent'),
        (OK, 'Okay')
    )

    userprofile = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile)
    language = models.ForeignKey(Language)
    proficiency = models.SmallIntegerField(choices=PROFICIENCY_CHOICES)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assuming the you mean on the front end and not in the admin. I believe that you can do this using a form set. (http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/). You would create a form for the through table to use in the formset.

Also, you may have simplified your models for posting, but if the language model is really just one choice field, why not just combine language and userprofile_language into one? You can replace the ForeignKey with the choice field and get the same behavior. That would make your display easier. (ignore this is language actually has more fields)

Comment: forms sets look like the right way to go with my current implementation but the documentation seems a bit simplistic.  are there better examples online?  With regard to just combining language and userprofile_language, that was my original implementation but from a pure DB view it seems wrong, plus I wasn't sure how to implement the forms for it either.